# no authorized_keys file in fedora

Tags: linux, hadoop, fedora

Hi i am installing hadoop in my machine,
i created a new group and a user under the group

```
[hduser@localhost ~]$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" Generating
public/private rsa key pair. Enter file in which to save the key
(/home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa):  Created directory '/home/hduser/.ssh'.
Your identification has been saved in /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa. Your
public key has been saved in /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. The key
fingerprint is: 30:1f:1f:5d:ef:52:16:41:7e:41:81:b4:62:17:87:36
hduser@localhost.localdomain The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+ |            .o*Oo| |           . E=.o| |      o . .ooo..=| |       + o..o  +.| |        S .   . .| |               . | |
| |                 | |                 |
+-----------------+
```

I did generated private key , with empty password and moved to authorized_keys.
next step is `cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

But still while connecting to ssh localhost, my new user is asking me to enter password. which i didn't generate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .ssh directory and the authorized_keys files should be owned by the user logging in, and only readable by that user.  The default ssh configuration will deny access if they are group or world readable.

Check for an entry in /var/log/audit that might explain.